# Extension methods to modify an async Task's type from Task<IEnumerable<T>> to Task<List<T>>

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, extension-methods, task-parallel-library

I've written a lot of `(await SomeTask).AsList();` in my project, and it's kind of annoying to keep wrapping it.

To fix this I've written a little extension method on `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` to be able to do this for me.

The code is like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Awaits the Task and returns the result as Task as List<T>.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the list.</typeparam>
/// <param name="task">The task to await.</param>
/// <returns>A task which returns as List which can be awaited.</returns>
public static async Task<List<T>> AsListAsync<T>(this Task<IEnumerable<T>> task)
{
    var result = await task;
    return result.AsList();
}

public static List<T> AsList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    if (enumerable is List<T> list)
    {
        return list;
    }

    return new List<T>(enumerable);
}
```

This enables me to write this:

```
_someProperty = await SomeMethod().AsListAsync();
```

instead of:

```
_someProperty = (await SomeMethod()).AsList();
```

However I am not sure if this will introduce any unintended behavior or deadlocking.
Can someone point out flaws in this code (if any)?

Comment: Why do you return `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` when you want `Task<List<T>>`?

Comment: What do you mean @BCdotWEB? I return a list. Some internal nuget package returns Task<IEnumerable<T>>, and I can't change the source of that package. That's why I have written this extension method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just two points to mention

- you should add documentation to the second method as well, because it is a `public` method **and** you have documented the first method as well.
- you should add a `null` check for the method parameters because one can call this methods directly as well, passing `null`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can implement the `AsListAsync` as a one-liner

```
public static async Task<List<T>> AsListAsync<T>(this Task<IEnumerable<T>> task)
    => await task is List<T> list ? list : new List<T>(task.Result);
```

Comment: Yes this should work, however the AsList() method is used throughout the project, My goal wasn't to make the extension as compact as possible, but to be easy to read/understand.

Comment: @Joost00719 Is it hard to read/understand? Is it too concise?

Comment: No it's not very hard to understand, it's just a code style preference. I posted my code here to learn whether my code has any flaws, or if it's code which I can push to production without worrying about.

Comment: @Joost00719 I can only see two concerns 1) If the `IEnumerable` contains fairly large amount of data then `AsList` can be time consuming. 2) It might happen in the future that you have to support `IAsyncEnumerable` as well, where `AsList` might require you to do some external calls as well.

Comment: @peter_Csla, thanks for the feedback! This wasn't something I thought of, and is good to know. Currently, I have no such case, so it isn't a problem for me (yet). I'll be putting a comment in the code that this is a possible issue if the dataset increases by a lot, or if the IEnumerable is IO bound.